# Run a node.js script as type "module" by creating a "temporary" package.json

Tags: node.js

I know I can run a node.js script as an ES Module by using the `.mjs` file extension or setting `"type": "module"` in `package.json`.  However, in many of my projects, it isn't practical to rename all my files `.mjs` or permanently set `"type": "module"` in the root `package.json`.  To work around this, I was thinking of setting `"type": "module"` in the `package.json` on the fly before I run the script, and then setting it back to `"type": "commonjs"` after the script has run.  This got me thinking, is there a way to take this approach a step further and create a "temporary" `package.json` on the fly and tell node.js to use it for the specific script?  Then I wouldn't have to modify the actual `package.json`?